# How to filter/modify backbone collection itself, not get a new array

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'd like to filter or run other functions on a Collection, but for the changes to remain with the collection, and not get a new array back.

For example:

In my Collection I have a few methods like:

```
approved:  ->
    filtered = @filter((model) ->
        model.get("status") is "approved"
    )
    return filtered


getSubcategories: (obj) ->
    ...
```

And in my View, at one point I may want the approved list of models, and then later on I want to run the getSubcategories method. But right now using these methods I'll just get back a new array.

How can I modify my Collection in the View without getting back a new array that I can no longer run other collection methods on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return a new instance of the collection, supplying it with the filtered array of models

```
approved:  ->
    filtered = @filter((model) ->
      model.get("status") is "approved"
    )
    new Example.Collection(filtered)
```